# How to use right click mouse to spam space button until I lift off the right click with no delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a script for agar.io that works with tampermonkey (just pasting code) and I copied this and it works and I modified it barely. Can someone fix it so that the right-click of mouse will spam the space button?

```
    $(
    function() {
        var rapiddown = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}); //spam space button
        var rapidup = $.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 32}); //spam space button
        var splitdown = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 32}); //space button
        var splitup = $.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 32}); //space button
        $(document).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
            if( (e.which == 3) ){
                $("body").trigger(rapiddown);
                $("body").trigger(rapidup);
                //console.log("feed");
            }
            else if( (e.which == 1) ){
                $("body").trigger(splitdown);
                $("body").trigger(splitup);
                //console.log("split");
            }
        }).bind('contextmenu', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        //alert("mouse enabled");
    }
)();
```